# How to access values of a ToolStrip item that was added dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripcontrolhost

Since only some standard items (textBox etc.) can be added to a [ToolStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e58c44b8(v=vs.110).aspx) control at design time in a Winform app, I've added a [DateTimePicker](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetimepicker) control dynamically as follows but I'm not sure how to access the datetime value of the selected date in the control

```
var datePicker = new ToolStripControlHost(new DateTimePicker());
toolStrip1.Items.Add(datePicker);
```

I've tried the following that still works as above but can't get access to the selected date value of the dateTimePicker added:

```
DateTimePicker myDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
var datePicker = new ToolStripControlHost(myDateTimePicker);
toolStrip1.Items.Add(datePicker);
```

This [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229625(v=vs.110).aspx) describes how to add items dynamically to ToolStrip but nothing else.

Comment: Make `myDateTimePicker` a property or field of the Form so you always have access to it. There is probably a way to name the tool strip item and find it, but it would not be as easy.

Comment: @Crowcoder I declared `public DateTimePicker myDateTimePicker { get; set; }` in the Form class but not sure how to use it in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `ValueChanged` event of the `DateTimePicker` this way:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = new ToolStripControlHost(new DateTimePicker());
    ((DateTimePicker)item.Control).ValueChanged += ToolStripDatePicker1_ValueChanged;
    item.Name = "ToolStripDatePicker1";
    toolStrip1.Items.Add(item);
}
private void ToolStripDatePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var datePicker = (DateTimePicker)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(datePicker.Value.ToString());
}
```

Also as another option, you can find the `DateTimePicker` control in another button click event handler this way:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((ToolStripControlHost)this.toolStrip1.Items["ToolStripDatePicker1"]);
    var datePicker = (DateTimePicker)item.Control;
    MessageBox.Show(datePicker.Value.ToString());
}
```

**Note:** A better solution would be deriving from `ToolStripControlHost`. This way you can expose properties and events which you need. For example, you can expose `Value` property and `ValueChanged` event of embedded `DateTimePicker` control.

The MSDN example [How to: Wrap a Windows Forms Control with ToolStripControlHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k5etstz(v=vs.110).aspx) shows you how to create a custom control to host in `ToolStrip`. You can simply use the example to create your custom `ToolStripDateTimePicker` control.

Comment: Thank you for helping me - it worked like a charm. Thank you for explaining it as well.